# Continuity between two topological spaces

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, continuity, homological-algebra, homotopy-theory

Let $Y$ is any convex subset of $\Bbb{R}^n$ and $I = [0,1]$.

Let $f, g: X \rightarrow Y$ be any two continuous maps.

Then I define a map $H: X \times I \rightarrow Y$ as

$H(x,t) = (1-t)f(x)+tg(x)$

I am trying to show that $H$ is continuous.

I define $k: I \rightarrow I$ as

$k(t) = 1-t$.

Then $k$ is continuous.

Therefore $\phi$ : $X \times I \rightarrow$ $Y \times I$ defined as

$\phi(x,t) = (f(x),1-t)$ is continuous.

From here, how can I claim that $H$ is continuous?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $(x,t) \to (f(x),g(x),t) $ and $(a,b,t) \to (1-t)a+tb$ are continuous maps and $H$ is the composition of these two.